# allowing for video within facebook app

Tags: facebook

i have been asked by a client to allow users to upload and post video within a facebook app.. was wondering whats the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All new apps are required to be iframe based. Tackle it the same way you would a regular website. All the Facebook integration happens server side or through javascript, not through FBML.

Comment: whats the best way to do it on a website then?

Comment: video is just a file, so you use standard HTML form syntax for upload. Playback depends on the format, but general you can again just use standard HTML to place the file on the page.